# ffmpeg av_parser_parse2 warnings and reading failure

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I try to read a video for saving its frames as images, and followed the code in example decode_video.c given at
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c

I use libs and dlls for ver 4.2.1

I found that calling av_parser_parse2 prints the follow warnings:

```
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] AVC-parser: nal size 1836019574 remaining 4064
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] SEI type 116 size 968 truncated at 168
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] Invalid NAL unit size (1836019574 > 4064).
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] missing picture in access unit with size 4096
```

Then, when proceeding to decode and calling avcodec_send_packet I get negative value (error) and the following is printed:

```
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] Invalid NAL unit size (1836019574 > 4064).
[h264 @ 000002b421e86040] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

1. How can I make it works?
2. I saw other examples that reads the stream without using av_parser_parse2, so it confuses me - do I need to use av_parser_parse2, or not? and if not using av_parser_parse2 - how the entire data from the video file is read - because avformat_open_input reads only the header...

Thanks

Comment: No, you don’t need to call parse. Try this as a guide. https://github.com/szatmary/libavinc/blob/master/libavinc.hpp

Comment: Thanks @szatmary , after checking and trying, you are right that there is no need to call parse, and yet, the link you gave is for a one that already familiar with the topic. It is much larger than what I need.
I just tried to read video and get frames images, and the examples I found were failed.